# Wrapper background image not covering full height of content

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I'm working with a template built via bootstrap framework, we have a background image in the wrapper, but when i'm viewing the website from a laptop 13'' screen, the text extends below the fold, the wrapper only covers above the fold, therefore my content isn't being displayed properly.

How can i fix this? Better yet, how can i make my content fit above the fold.

Comment: you shouldnt link to your personal website in your questions, please use http://jsfiddle.net/ if you need to demonstrate an issue

Comment: Can you share JSFIDDLE URL. Hope you are trying to fix background image size issue. if you are trying to fix background size issue in different resolution just make `background-size: 100%`

Comment: JSFIDDLE URL: http://jsfiddle.net/L72wwz7g/